# Ошибка при вычислении числа с использованием библиотеки boost

Tags: c++, boost

Имею код:

```
vector<vector<int128_t>> resh(n, vector<int128_t>(n, 0));
int128_t S = 0;
int128_t R = 0;
int128_t qs = (1019 - 1) / 2;
int64_t x = 0;
```

При расчете `x`:

```
x = int64_t(-resh[k.convert_to<size_t>()][0] * S - R) % qs;
```

Выдает ошибку:

> невозможно преобразовать
>   "boost::multiprecision::number,boost::multiprecision::et_off>" в "int64_t"

Никак не могу понять почему?

Comment: потому что int64_t ничего не знает о бустовом классе, как собственно и буст. Поэтому так просто взять и кастануть нельзя

Comment: и как быть? как перевести из boost в обычный вид?

Comment: в `size_t` же ты преобразовал с помощью, `convert_to<size_t>`, как думаешь, как теперь в `int64_t` преобразовать?

Comment: спасибо большое)